# How to use find command to get csv

Tags: linux, shell, unix, find, ls

I am using the following command:

```
$ find /mnt/DCS_01 -size +10000k -exec ls -sd {} +
26412032 /mnt/DCS_01/file.mp3
26412032 /mnt/DCS_01/file2.mp3
```

I am trying to write this as a `csv` file. Is there a way to get the output as comma-separated, so I can write it to a text file, for example:

```
$ find /mnt/DCS_01 -size +10000k -exec ls -sd {} + "csv" > file.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `-printf` :

```
find /mnt/DCS_01 -size +10000k -printf '%k,"%p"\n'
```

Read about printf :

```
man find | less +/'-printf format'
```

Comment: Thank you -- how would I get that in human-readible form for size? For example, 3.4GB ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `printf` --

```
$ find /mnt/DCS_01 -size +10000k -printf '%s,%p\n'
29038348776,/mnt/DCS_01/file1...
919345944,/mnt/DCS_01/file2...
```

Comment: %s is not the same size as OP output

Comment: @GillesQuenot what is `%s` then? Isn't is `              %s     File’s size in bytes.
` ?